# How can I change port on nginx.conf by command line mac os?

Tags: macos, vue.js, nginx, localhost, nginx-config

If I run : `vim /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` on command line it show like this :

[image]
I want to change port to 80

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean you don't understand `vim`? If so, just use a different editor like **TextEdit**.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or data - they are very hard to use for testing!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to edit your `nginx.conf` from the command-line like this:

```
sed -E 's/listen[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+/listen 80/' nginx.conf
```

That says... *"wherever you see the word `listen` followed by one or more spaces then one or more digits, replace that with `listen 80`"*

If the output looks correct, you can edit the file in place with the `-i` switch:

```
sed -E -i.bak 's/listen[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+/listen 80/' nginx.conf
```

which also makes a backup file in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score -1):

1. Change `8080` to `80` and [save](https://www.howtoforge.com/vim-basics).
2. Restart nginx:

```sh
# Make sure the syntax is OK.
sudo nginx -t
# Then restart
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: Yeah. But How can I edit it on command line? I tried to edit directly in the command line. but that can't be

Comment: Please update your answer with detail answer(nano command or vim)